# How to centrate an element within <div?

Tags: html

So, I have this code

```
<div id="timer"> </div>
```

How can I centrate this in HTML5? I tried  but as far I as know, it's obsolete for HTML5 and I must use CSS
Any help?

Comment: please provide some code

Comment: @Error70 Yeah, sorry. Now it should appear in the question

Answer (score 1):

You can't (or, more specifically, **shouldn't**) do any kind of styling in HTML, that's what the CSS exists for.

The `text-align` property could be a beginning.

Here is a great source of information : https://www.w3schools.com/css/

Comment: Oh Matte', io ti ho solo chiesto come faccio a centrare quel porc'iddio di codice, non lezioni sul css :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using **Flexbox**. Try below code snippet it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
#parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="timer">Timer</div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Do I must insert the #parent code into <style>?

Comment: Yes, you have to add #parent CSS, because flexbox CSS apply on the parent container. Thanks

Comment: Still not working... A thing I didn't said, its that the text (timer) i want to align to the center, it's a countdown from 60 to 0
Maybe that's the problem

Comment: can you share the link? Thanks